# Find exact match in attribute value though there are other strings that contain a part of the substring

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_190');render_selected_term('190','1','275531','AQCB Number')" value="190" name="radio_190"/>

<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_179');render_selected_term('179','1','275531','AQCB Number (iLink)')" value="179" name="radio_179"/>
```

The above is the DOM structure of two radio buttons and I need to do an exact match on its name. The name of the radio button is the last parameter of 'render_selected_term' attribute. How can I do that?

Comment: you forgot something

Comment: err, the above what? No DOM here.

Comment: i did add the DOM. Hold on!

Comment: Done! Any suggestions?

Comment: Can u please give me the syntax on how to use it for my scenario? @Raghavendra

Comment: you can try this //input[@type='radio' and contains(@onclick, 'render_selected_term')][last()]

Comment: Every radio button contains 'render_selected_term' as its attribute. It is matching all the radio buttons.  //input[@type='radio' and contains(@onclick, 'AQCB Number')][last()] still gives me two matches as we are using contains. I want to select only the first one or the second one.

Comment: last will always returns only one element or null

Comment: True, but //input[@type='radio' and contains(@onclick, 'AQCB Number')][last()] is a match for both the elements.

Comment: try this //input[@type='radio' and contains(@onclick, 'AQCB Number')[count(//input[@type='radio' and contains(@onclick, 'AQCB Number'))]

Comment: It is not helping. I dont think using contains will solve the problem, as both the text we are searching contains the same pattern of alphabets, just that one of it contains a word extra. Can we have a text() match in the previously mentioned xpath?

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj : The radio buttons must be accompanied with some text/label. I think that can be used for applying a text-based xpath. So, can you please provide your HTML code accordingly ?

Comment: @Raghavendra please don't put answers as comments. Post them as an answer.

Comment: Please add code for what you have tried and what the result was so we can better direct you.

Comment: @Raghavendra, I think this logic might work. Let me check it and accept the solution

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj you can also do like this //input[@type='radio' and contains(@onclick, 'AQCB Number')[count(following-sibling::input[@type='radio' and contains(@onclick, 'AQCB Number'))=0]

Comment: @Raghavendra this is still giving multiple matches. I am suggesting that this is because of the contains expression. Do we have any way to match the exact text instead of contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work based on the HTML you provided. Basically I pull all the `INPUT` tags (you may have to tweak this to be more specific and only pull the right `INPUT` tags) and loop through them looking for the `onclick` attribute. I `.split()` the full `onclick` string by comma to get the last part (e.g. `'AQCB Number (iLink)'`) then remove the `'`s and `)` and put that into `name`. At that point you can just compare the pulled name to the name you are looking for and then do whatever you need to do.

```
String requestedName = "AQCB Number"; // sample string for testing
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='radio']"));
for (WebElement input : inputs)
{
    String onclick = input.getAttribute("onclick");
    String[] parts = onclick.split(",");
    String name = parts[parts.length - 1];
    name = name.substring(1, name.length() - 2);
    System.out.println(name); // for debug purposes
    if (name.equals(requestedName))
    {
        // name match, do stuff here...
    }
}
```